# data security and scan

Tags: linux

What does "savscand" does in CentOS environment?

I am asking this because it takes the CPU level to 100% for about 5 minutes every day.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     22082  0.7  1.1 137724 91376 ?        Sl   03:26   1:02 savscand --incident=unix://tmp/incident --control=msq://98304.1/98304.2 socketpair://24/28 socketpair:
//29/35 socketpair://36/41 socketpair://42/45 socketpair://48/50
```

Or may be there must be some other reason, but I can not figure it out.

Comment: Sophos Antivirus Scanner Daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Sophos Antivirus as others have pointed out. It's updating it's definitions. Sophos has taken a somewhat inefficient approach to updates, it reinstalls the entire AV package. The upside is that an update will fix any damage to the program (intentional or accidental). The downside as you have noticed is that it pegs the system during the update.

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests it is Sophos Antivirus.  It probably pegs the CPU because it's doing a periodic scan of the entire system, or it might be updating it's signatures in an unpleasantly inefficient fashion.

My opinion of AV is poor, and I'd probably remove it.  You may have a different opinion.